# Access nested relationship data laravel

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

The image tells more accurate question instead of a detailed description, that s why i am attatching an image.

**How can i access the following relationship data in laravel.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got what i needed. Answer is here

```
@foreach($record as $data)
    {{ $data['Cities'][0]['cities'] -> name }}
@endforeach
```